# JMeter - Saving post data from http requst sample to the csv file

Tags: jmeter

I have a Http request with Body Data which can create individual user any time when it runs for example:

```
{"username":"fakeuser${__RandomString(5,abcdefghijklmnofqrst1234567,userno)}","email":"fakeuser${userno}@fakedomain.com","password":"blblabla123!","passwordRepeated":"blablabla123!"}

POST Data:
{"username":"fakeuser4mf7s","email":"fakeuser4mf7s@fakedomain.com","password":"blablabla123!","passwordRepeated":"blablabla123!"}
```

Is there any way to grab email and password value from the Post Data and save it to the same csv file any time when specific http request sample runs.

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) as a chid of the HTTP Request sampler
2. Put the following code into "Script" area:

   ```
   import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

   def request = new JsonSlurper().parseText(sampler.getArguments().getArgument(0).getValue())
   def email = request.email
   def password = request.password

   new File('test.csv') << email + ',' + password + System.getProperty('line.separator')
   ```

Once you execute your test the JSR223 PostProcessor will add the values of `email` and `password` objects into `test.csv` file (normally it should reside in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

References:

- [Groovy: Parsing and Producing JSON](http://groovy-lang.org/json.html)
- [Groovy Goodness: Working with Files](http://mrhaki.blogspot.it/2009/08/groovy-goodness-working-with-files.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)